# Is there any way to decode decision tree probablity output?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

My code is available on google colab

[Code for indetail information](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jhQL7ImIGQTw8XwZQQFIR_66YcCcOIga?usp=sharing)

I have made one algorithm where I use a decision tree for multiple probability prediction

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X1, Y1
                                        , test_size=0.4,
                                        random_state=1)



model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')

# Train the model using the training sets and check score
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

score= model.score(X1, Y1)
print('Score:- \n',score)

multi2 = model.predict_proba(X_test)
```

I am getting this

```
 [array([[1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.],
        [1.]]),
 array([[1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [0., 1.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [0., 1.],
        [1., 0.]])]
```

while trying to decode facing this issue

```
vnc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
vnc.fit(Y1)
vnc.inverse_transform(multi2)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (38,1) into shape (38)
```

My output should be :

```
[[decode_value1,decode_value2,decode_value3,decode_value4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The i'th row in the output of `predict_proba` contains an length 2 array containing the probability of the positive and negative class (which means that they should sum to 1) of the i'th sample in the array you passed to it.

By default, `DecisionTreeClassifier` splits until all nodes are pure, i.e., contain a single value.

The scikit-learn documentation states:

> The predicted class probability is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf.

This means that if all leaves in the decision tree contain a single value (which is the default case, i.e., `max_depth=None`), `predict_proba` will always output a probability of 1 for the predicted class.

It makes sense to set `max_depth` to a reasonable positive integer, depending on the size of your dataset. It'll help regulate overfitting, especially if you have a small dataset, and you'll observe `predict_proba` outputting something other than just 0 and 1.

Refer:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem same prediction array I got @Nikhil Kumar

Comment: I have resize predicted output and inverse with tested data so it's work for me.